# SQL Server 2012 Replication

Tags: replication, sql-server-2012

Please help me out with a problem I am facing.

I have a table T. I altered the table to alter the column C from varchar (10) to varchar (100).

Now, there is a view V that is schema bound and selects columns from T. So before altering T, I had to drop the view V.

Steps I followed: 1. Drop view V 2. Alter T alter C varchar (100) 3. (re)create V

Error I am facing: Replication-Replication Distribution Subsystem: agent XXX failed. The object 'V' is dependent on column 'C'. I performed the changes in Preprod environment. Table T is in replication.

I want to know: 1. How to fix this error 2. what did I do wrong?

Comment: please note that i made these changes in SQL server management studio. Such chnages are not propogated down to subscribers According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151870.aspx.. Only  changes made by using Transact-SQL or SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) are

Comment: I managed to fix this issue. 

Reason: the error occurred because of the schema bound view V on the subscriber DB as well. The schema bound view was not letting SQL Server replicate the changes made to T.C

My learning: Column changes (datatypes) along with a whole bunch of other schema changes made  on publisher db get automatically replicated onto the subscriber DBs (refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151870.aspx).

Fix: I just dropped view V on the subscriber DB for a few minutes to let replication make the DDL changes in the subscriber DB and recreated it afterwards.

Comment: Posting it here as Stack exchange wont let me answer my own question :)